# how to log console to a text file and delete old text file when it reaches a set size

Tags: python, logging, console

two parts:

1. Using python, I want to write everything from stdout to a log file. I found a good solution for this part, but,
2. I'm also looking for a way to delete the file when it gets too big and start a new file. Usually the info going to the display is not useful so I don't care about it, but when an error occurs, I'd like to have captured it to a file to see what lead up to it.

I could write a function that checks the file size and starts a new file when the current file reaches a particular size, but I'm wondering if something exists to do this.

I would like my test program to run for weeks, constantly outputting to the display and a text file, but creating a new text file when the current one gets too big, so basically a circular buffer that wraps around.

Comment: see [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) if you use module `logging`

Comment: @furas -  RotatingFileHandler works for me in python2.73. thx